# Rstudio for Windows 8.1 (64bit)?

Tags: r, windows-8, rstudio

Where I can find and download Rstudio for Windows 8.1 (64bit). I have R installed version 4.3.1.

thanks in advance

the latest version of the site doesn't work on my computer, r studio crashes. I need some version which can run on Windows 8.1 with R already installed  (version 4.3.1).

Comment: There is no standard installer for windows for any version other than Win 10/11.  I suggest taking your question to the posit forums:  https://community.rstudio.com/

Comment: You could go back to a much earlier version of RStudio but I don't know which was the last version to support win 8.1 64bit.  If you have the option (i.e. have sufficient admin rights) you could run a dual boot with a linux version or a virtual machine with a supported distro.

Comment: Windows 8.1 is no longer supported. You therefore *should not use it*, because **it is a security liability:** unless you are on an airgapped system that is not connected to the internet, you *will* get hacked. It’s just a question of time. Lack of RStudio support is the least of your issues at this point.